# Как переконвертировать .NET Core проект в .Net Framework на линуксе или онлайн?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, msbuild

Сейчас пишу тестовое задание на .Net Core (.Net Standard 2.0) на линуксе (Mint 19.1). Но проверяющий наверняка будет смотреть мое решение на Windows в Visual Studio без установленного .Net Core SDK. Устанавливать второй системой Windows долго и муторно. Windows в виртуалке мой ноутбук не потянет (4 гигабайта ОЗУ).

Потому задаюсь вопросом, есть ли на linux какой-нибудь конвертор проекта с .Net Core на встроенный в Windows 10 .Net Framework 4.6.1? Или может есть онлайн-сервис по пересборке .Net проектов на разные версии .Net Framework и .Net Core?

Comment: Это на курсы задание? Или в универ?

Comment: Это не то чтобы ответ, но Windows 7 x32 выживет на 1 ГБ ОЗУ. Если обойтись без Visual Studio (собирать через MSBuild), то может получиться протестировать на виртуалке.

Comment: Я думаю, проект небольшой, поэтому будет проще просто создать на компьютере проверяющего проект .NET Framework и все исходники перенести туда.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko на работу, но по смыслу задания и сложности это лабораторка в универ

Comment: @MaboUhha а какого типа проект у вас? .NET Core библиотека классов? Что-то другое?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko консоль и к ней библиотеки, все на .Net Core, да

Comment: 'Visual Studio без установленного .Net Core SDK' проверяющие специально его удалил или студия старая?

Comment: Mono на линухе рассматривали?

Answer (score 2):

> переконвертировать .NET Core проект в .Net Framework на линуксе

Смотря, что Вы хотите сконвертировать. Если Вы не выходите за рамки .NET Standard, то проблем быть не должно. Но, если речь идёт о других типах проектов (тот же ASP.NET), то здесь всё гораздо сложнее. Всё-таки .NET Framework это про Windows.

> проверяющий наверняка будет смотреть мое решение на Windows в Visual
>   Studio без установленного .Net Core SDK

Зачем пользователю приложения для работы с ним Visual Studio и пр.? Сделайте нормальный инсталлятор в котором будет упакована уже собранная рабочая версия с нужными зависимостями и киньте ему с инструкцией как установить проект.

Comment: В Visual Studio скорей всего будут смотреть код. Скомпилированную консоль я, конечно, передам, и, на 50% уверен, что проблем быть не должно, так как за .net standard не выхожу

Comment: Извините за нескромный вопрос. Это задание хотя бы символически оплачивается?

Comment: Просто лично я очень не доверяю компаниям, которые дают бесплатные тестовые задания. Особенно, если они ещё просят код. Надеюсь, Вы меня поймёте правильно.

Comment: Нет, но оно небольшое, кодирования буквально часа на 3-4

Comment: 4 часа это уже половина рабочего дня. В прочем, смотрите сами, Вам жить.

Comment: Ну и задание никак не связано с деятельностью фирмы. Обычное задание на ООП и паттерны проектирования а-ля лабораторка в универ

Comment: Не знаю. Я просто высказал своё мнение.

Answer (score 1):

`.NET Framework 4.6.1` поддерживает `.Net Standard 2.0`
главное не использовать библиотеки строго под `.net Core`
[вот](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-implementation-support) ссылка на таблицу совместимости

Comment: Это ясно. Я потому и написал конкретную целевую версию фреймворка. Проблема в том, что проверяющему будет вломы ставить себе .Net Core SDK, а мне вломы ставить Windows, только чтобы переконвертировать проект. Вот и пытаюсь найти какой-то компромисс

Comment: Почему об этом не договорились сразу? И наверняка у Вашего софта были требования к платформе...

Comment: @Streletz ну задание мне дали на днях, а линуксу на моей машине пара месяцев. Конечно, поговорить можно было, но ответ, по-моему, очевиден - это я к ним трудоустраиваюсь, а не наоборот

Comment: Если так и Вам очень нужна эта работа, то ответ относительно линуса и винды то же очевиден (ИМХО). Если конечно Вы с ними не договоритесь..

Comment: Всяко лучше спросить здесь сначала (конвертор вряд ли существует, конечно, а сборочный онлайн-сервис вполне может быть реален, как мне кажется), чем потратить лишние 3 часа жизни =) Работать планирую только на машине работодателя, так что Windows дома мне нужен только для конвертации

Comment: Как гласит мудрость: "Не зарекайся - жизнь поднимет планку".